# Is the JavaScript import statement used only to import frameworks?

Tags: javascript, import, frameworks

Is the JavaScript import statement only used to import frameworks, or can it be used to import other things? What other things can it be used to import?

Comment: You can import any javascript file

Answer (score 0):

You can import variables, objects and basically anything as long as it's JavaScript. Note that frameworks usually export an object.

```
// file.js
export const a = 30;

// default.js
const object = { a: (param) => doSomething(param), ... };
export default object;

// main.js
import { a } from "file.js";       // console.log(a) -> 30
import Whatever from "default.js"; // import and name the default export
```